# PDO: INSERT no funciona pero SELECT si funciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola estoy haciendo un registro con PDO, cuando hago un SELECT * FROM, si funciona, pero al momento de querer guardar la información en la BD, no me da ningun error pero tampoco guarda la información en la BD.

**db.php**

```
function pdo_connect_mysql() {
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    try{
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registrosdb, $db_user, $db_pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit('Failed to connect to database!');
    }
}
```

**proceso_registro.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once 'db.php';


    $pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();


    //Verificamos que este enviando desde el formulario
    if(isset($_POST['registrar'])){

        $email = filter_var($_POST['txtEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $pass = filter_var($_POST['txtPass'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $pass2 = filter_var($_POST['txtPass2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $fecha_registro = date('Y-d-m');

        //Verificamos que las contraseñas sean identicas
        if($pass === $pass2){
            //Verificamos que el email NO exista en la base de datos.

            $sql_verifyuser = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_app WHERE email = ?";
            $sql_verifyuser  = $pdo->prepare($sql_verifyuser);
            $sql_verifyuser ->execute(array($email));
            $resp_verifyuser = $sql_verifyuser ->fetch();
            if($resp_verifyuser){
                header('Location: ../login.php?email_existe');
            }
            $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $codigo_activacion = md5( $pass.time() );

            //Insertamos en la tabla usuarios_app
            $sql_insertuser = "INSERT INTO usuarios_app(email,contrasenia,fecha_registro,estatus,codigo_activacion,id_rolf) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $sql_insertuser  = $pdo->prepare($sql_insertuser);
            $sql_insertuser->execute(array(
                $email, $pass, $fecha_registro,1,$codigo_activacion,3
            ));


            if($sql_insertuser){
                echo "ok";
            }else{
                echo "error";
            }


        }else{
            header('Location: ../login.php?contrasenias_no_validas');
        }            
    }else{
        header('Location: ../login.php');
    }
```

Comment: Añade un print_r(mysqli_error($pdo)) dentro del ese donde muestras el echo error, así podrás ver qué problema te da la consulta. Aparentemente parece cosa de que no engloba los parámetros bien...

Comment: utilice  print_r($sql_insertuser->errorInfo()); y encontré el error, era por el formato de fecha, en la bd es Y-m-d y en la consulta estaba como Y-d-m. Error tonto. Gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: @Jakala `mysqli_error` no funciona con PDO. Luis, usa `print_r($sql_insertuser->errorInfo());` para depurar únicamente. Una vez que el código funcione cámbialo por un mensaje personalizado, pues no conviene nunca mostrar errores internos. Precisamente PDO en algunos escenarios revela incluso la contraseña cuando el código falla.

Comment: Si, fallo mío. No leí que estaba usando PDO. Gracias